# Flutter bottom navigation design

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I need some help regarding the design I am very new to the flutter could anybody help me how to achieve it as I tried in the googling as well but can't able find any solution

[image]

Tried some pages getting below issue

Curve is moving somewhere

[image]

```
    class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
        floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
          elevation: 2.0,
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 32.0, right: 32.0, bottom: 32.0),
          child: BottomAppBar(
            child: Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: Image.asset('assets/images/account.png',
                      width: 32.0, height: 32.0, fit: BoxFit.contain),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Image.asset('assets/images/settings.png',
                      width: 32.0, height: 32.0, fit: BoxFit.contain),
                )
              ],
            ),
            shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Text('Home Page'),
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Scaffold has a special parameter for positioning the FAB. 

`floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked`

u can check the example https://codewithandrea.com/articles/bottom-bar-navigation-with-fab/

Comment: Hi @SergeiMikhailovskii I had tried that getting the issue with the fab curve i had updated my question please check it

Comment: Can you provide code-snippet?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I had updated the question with snippet please check it

Comment: Does it have to be exact like your attached image, or If it is ok to just have `CircularNotchedRectangle` on correct position?

Comment: Its should be exact as the image attached

Comment: @YeasinSheikh if we can make the CirecularNotchedRectangle to center is fine could you please help me regarding it

Comment: I think you can follow @osama 's answer for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {[![enter image description here][1]][1]
  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        extendBody: true,
        floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
        floatingActionButton: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15, left: 20),
          child: Material(
            color: Colors.purple,
            shape:
                RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(35)),
            elevation: 10,
            shadowColor: Colors.purple,
            child: Container(
              height: 70.0,
              width: 70.0,
              child: FloatingActionButton(
                backgroundColor: Colors.purple,
                onPressed: () {},
                child: const Icon(Icons.add),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10, bottom: 15),
          child: BottomAppBar(
            color: Colors.transparent,
            clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
            shape: const CircularNotchedRectangle(),
            notchMargin: 0,
            elevation: 10,
            // color: Colors.g,
            child: Container(
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15))),
                child: SizedBox(
                  height: kToolbarHeight,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: const [
                        Expanded(
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.perm_identity,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.heart_broken_outlined,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                )

         
                ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

here is a bit more to your code it ain't exactly what you are trying to achieve but I hope this will help

[image]